# how do i get multi-line input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am trying to get the user to answer multiple inputs at once rather one at a time.

example:
this asks for the users input one at a time

```
q1=input("question1: ")

q2=input("question2: ")

print(q1)

print(q2)

... question1: answer1
... question2: answer2

answer1
answer2

>>>
```

this is what i would like to do.

```
q1=input("""
question1: 
question2: """)

print(q1)


...question1: answer1
   question2: answer2 

[answer1,answer2]

>>>
```

by letting the user enter all inputs at once it will let them see all of the questions and they can make changes before they confirm their input.

my end goal is to be able to do this:

```
q=input("""
url:
resolution:
audio only:
file type:
download location: 
""")
print(q)

...url: youtube.com/video
   resolution: 720p
   audio only: False
   file type: mp4
   download location: C:\videos

[youtube.com/video,720p,False,mp4,C:\videos]
```

Edit:

i know how to get multiple outputs and concatenate them into a list.

multi output is not my main goal.

my main goal is multiple inputs all at the same time not one input at a time.

Edit 2:

if it helps the input can be in other forms e.g.text boxes/buttons or extra modules.
example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/deKOb.png

Comment: I don't about the multiline input however for the output, you could concatenate the inputs to format it the way you want as a string or a list

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to get multiple answers:

```
print ("Enter the below details")
question = ["url:","resolution:","audio only:","file type:","download location:"]
answer = []
for q in question:
    answer.append(input(q))

print(answer)
```

Output:
`['www.google.com', '720', 'False', 'mp4', 'c:\\videos']`

Comment: this doesn't do multi line input. this lets the user answer multiple inputs one at a time.

Comment: @Yolo Gammer Then you can enter input by comma separated and then split using comma and use for further processing

Comment: i am trying to make my code user friendly so commas are out of the question because there can be some confusion and there is a higher chance human error

Comment: @Yolo Gammer Then its difficult to get multi line input.We cant use the enter as a separator

Comment: Enter doesn't have to be used as a separator because the user will click on the line they want to enter data into

Comment: I don't think it is possible with input(). One better way ask question first and then iterate loop 5 times and append answers.

Comment: the input can be in other forms e.g.text boxes/buttons or extra modules i just need to have a user friendly input that will let the user enter data into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate lists of questions and answers. Then loop through questions for getting user input and add user input to the answers list.

```
questions = [
   "url: ",
   "resolution: ",
   "audio only: ",
   "file type: ",
   "download location: ",
   ]

answers = []

for question in questions:
    answer = input(question)
    answers.append(answer)

print(answers)
```

Comment: this doesn't do multi line input. this lets the user answer multiple inputs one at a time.

Comment: @Yolo Gamer, if you want the user to be able to click on a question and type the answer, I'm afraid it's not feasible given the command-line interface. You may need to use a gui.